# How to detect that a web page reload has been canceled using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was trying to capture the event of canceling a page reload with JavaScript, as I want this pass to call a method to cancel a behavior that I implement when the page reloads.

I have been trying some JavaScript posible solutions such as event.clientY, eventlistener but nothing has worked for me. In my project i don't use angular, nodejs, etc.

Comment: I don't think it's possible because while page reload is an event, cancelling the reload isn't considered an event. You'd need to make the two pieces of code communicate with each other.

Comment: Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming You might be able to do something with unloadEventStart and unloadEventEnd